# 完全パネルデータの作成にあたり、観測期間(年次データ)のすべてが揃った個体のデータのみを、新しいデータフレームに保存したいです

Tags: r

使用するデータは多少簡略化していますが、以下のようなものです。

name    year    ...
A社    1999    ...
A社    2000    ...
A社    2001    ...
A社    2002    ...
B社    1999    ...
B社    2000    ...
C社    2001    ...
C社    2002    ...
D社    1999    ...
D社    2000    ...
D社    2001    ...
E社    2002    ...

この中から1999年∼2001年のデータが'全て'揃っている企業のみを新しいデータフレームに保存したいです。目標は以下の形になります。
name    year    ...
A社    1999    ...
A社    2000    ...
A社    2001    ...
D社    1999    ...
D社    2000    ...
D社    2001    ...

Answer (score 1):

**標準関数**

```r
dfx <- do.call('rbind',
  c(by(df, df$name, function(x) {
      f <- x$year %in% 1999:2001
      if (sum(f)==3) x[f,]
    }), make.row.names=F))

print(dfx)
#
  name year
1  A社 1999
2  A社 2000
3  A社 2001
5  D社 1999
6  D社 2000
7  D社 2001
```

**dplyr**

```r
library(dplyr)

dfx <-
  df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  filter({f=year %in% 1999:2001;sum(f)==3&f})

print(dfx)
#
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   name [2]
  name   year
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A社    1999
2 A社    2000
3 A社    2001
4 D社    1999
5 D社    2000
6 D社    2001
```

Answer (score 1):

パネルデータとして扱いたいということなら, たぶん plm パッケージを使っていると思います. よって一般に完全 (バランスド) パネルデータを作成する `make.pbalanced` を使えば良いと思います. ただし今回は1999-2001年に絞るという特殊な条件も課しているので, まず年インデックスで絞り込んでから適用することになります.

```
require(plm)
d <- pdata.frame(d, index = c("name", "year"), row.names = F)
make.pbalanced(subset(d, year %in% 1999:2001), "shared.individuals")
```